# css inheritence - quiz12

Tags: css

What will be the text size “Universe” with the below declaration

```
<div style=”font-size:12px;”>World is<div style=”font-size:0.5em;”>VERY small in <div style=”font-size:100%;”>Universe</div></div></div>
```

1. 12px
2. 6px
3. font size specified for BODY
4. Varies from browser to browser

I encountered this question in a quiz. Option 4, tempt me to post this question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% of 12 * .5 is 6.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 6px

Answer (score 0):

A must read in this context

Although Percentages and Ems are arguably the best method for font sizing, there are two main problems to overcome:

1. Consistency across browsers
2. Inheritance and its effect on nested items

Consistency across browsers

Browsers interpret relative font sizing in different ways, especially in relation to inheritance. One example would be setting font size in the body tag:

body { font-size: 80%; }

Most browsers will render this as being 80% of the element's default font behaviour. A standard H1 will render at 200% default font size, so with the rule above applied to the page, an H1 would become 160% (200% x 80%= 160%) of default font size.

Mac/Opera6 will not apply this rule consistently across content. Text within tables stays at default size. Mac/Netscape4 and Win/Netscape4 will apply this rule to headings as well as text within paragraph tags - making all content on the page 80% size.
Inheritance and its effect on nested items

Relative font sizing also runs into problems with inheritance and its effect on nested items. For example, a rule like the one below can cause inheritance problems:

p, ul { font-size: 85%; }

A sample showing paragraph and unordered nested list problem.

Any content within a paragraph or unordered list will be scaled to 80% of the user's default browser size. The problem occurs when there is a nested unordered list. The nested list item will inherit the relative font sizing and apply it again, making the nested list items 72.25% in size (85% x 85% = 72.25%).

This is easily fixed with another rule that will bring all nested list items back to 85% font size:

ul ul { font-size: 100%; }

More here

[Relative font sizes and inheritance](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/relative/)